# slow concurrent file access with wildcards in linux

Tags: linux, filesystems

on a linux system I have a directory with about 100.000 files (they contain some statistics data). I have to access them using wildcards and now I experience some performance issues.
When accessing a specific file it's really fast:

```
time ls 19991
19991

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

When using wildcards it's (as you would expect) slower:

```
time ls 19991*
19991

real    0m0.043s
user    0m0.020s
sys     0m0.020s
```

But: When I try to access the files concurrently ALL access get slow:

```
 i=1; while [ $i -le 10 ]; do (time ls 19991* &) ; let i=i+1; done 
19991
19991

real    0m0.248s
user    0m0.010s
sys     0m0.020s
19991

real    0m0.279s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.040s
19991
19991
19991

real    0m0.306s
user    0m0.050s
sys     0m0.000s

real    0m0.236s
user    0m0.010s
sys     0m0.030s

real    0m0.257s
user    0m0.010s
sys     0m0.040s

real    0m0.263s
user    0m0.020s
sys     0m0.020s
19991
19991

real    0m0.196s
user    0m0.030s
sys     0m0.010s

real    0m0.175s
user    0m0.020s
sys     0m0.020s
19991

real    0m0.095s
user    0m0.040s
sys     0m0.000s
19991

real    0m0.158s
user    0m0.020s
sys     0m0.040s
```

Even if the access is serialized by the kernel, I would expect the first "ls" to take about 40ms, the second 80ms, the third 120ms, ... . But now even the fastest "ls" takes 95ms and most of them about 200ms.

This occurs when using a local filesystem (ext3) and also when using a network-mounted directory (nfs). So I think it has nothing to do with a specific filesystem.

Any ideas what causes this slowdown or how to fix it?

Comment: Which kernel version are you using?

Comment: Kernel serialize the access to the mass storage but not the creation of your processes. It's possibile that up to 10 `ls 19991*` are running togheter pretenting to access to the same resource

Comment: @Colin'tHart: I experience this behaviour with different (rather old :-( ) kernel  versions (2.4.7, 2.6.9 and 2.6.18)

Comment: @DavideBerra  When access is serialized: shouldn't at least one process finish after about 40ms? Why is it affected by the other processes started afterwards?

Comment: @chrikoch i guess you have doubt because you think every command is ran by the OS that release resources and pass to the next command only when the one before is completed. But (simplified case) the OS complete the 10% of the task of the first command, then pass to the second one, complete his 10% then pass to third ecc ecc... until every command is 100% completed.

Answer (score 0):

What is the total time used?

If I look at the user time and the sys time, then they are still small. So maybe this is what you see:

```
init job1
init job2
init job3
...
init job10
run half of job1
...
run half of job10
finish jobs1
...
finish jobs10
```

Compare these:

```
$ time ( i=1; while [ $i -le 100 ]; do time ls 19991* &  let i=i+1; done ;wait)
real    0m1.278s
user    0m2.532s
sys     0m2.236s

$ time ( i=1; while [ $i -le 100 ]; do time ls 19991* ; let i=i+1; done ;wait)
real    0m3.197s
user    0m1.669s
sys     0m1.535s
```

User and sys is roughly the same. The longer user+sys-time in the parallel version can be explained by the overhead of forking. The lower real time can be explained by having multiple CPUs.

So your timing is heavily affected by more jobs running in parallel.